# php mail() with attachment returns noname.txt

Tags: php, email

I am using php `mail()` function with **attachment** using `Content-Type: multipart/mixed` header but it always return **noname.txt**

Here is my codes:

```
$upload_name=$_FILES["upload"]["name"];
$upload_type=$_FILES["upload"]["type"];
$upload_size=$_FILES["upload"]["size"];
$upload_temp=$_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
$subject = "Subject";
$to="example@example.com";
$message="message";

    $fp = fopen($upload_temp, "rb");
$file = fread($fp, $upload_size);

$file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
$num = md5(time());

    //Normal headers

$headers  = "From: Info Mail<example@example.com>\r\n";
   $headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers  .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
   $headers  .= "boundary=".$num."\r\n";
   $headers  .= "--$num\r\n";

    // This two steps to help avoid spam

$headers .= "Message-ID: <".gettimeofday()." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\r\n";

    // With message

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
   $headers .= "".$message."\n";
   $headers .= "--".$num."\n";

    // Attachment headers

$headers  .= "Content-Type:".$upload_type." ";
   $headers  .= "name=\"".$upload_name."\"r\n";
   $headers  .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
   $headers  .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
   $headers  .= "filename=\"".$upload_name."\"\r\n\n";
   $headers  .= "".$file."\r\n";
   $headers  .= "--".$num."--";
// SEND MAIL
   $flgchk=@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 fclose($fp);
```

In Mail Inbox It Returns:

[image]

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: i think you are getting issue in you mime type of file which you are uploading at this line  $headers  .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";

Comment: @Ricky Then, what can i use instead of _Content-Type: multipart/mixed_?

Comment: I recommend to use an e-mail library like `SwiftMailer`. Then it's really easy to send e-mails with attachements and different encodings etc.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Thank You, but libraries like PHPMailer, SwiftMailer,... confuses me, that's not easy to understand.

Comment: @edCoder you must have to check mime type of file while uploading it by using php mime type type function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php .

Comment: after that apply that mime type to $headers  .= "Content-Type:".$mime_type." ";

Comment: Just remove the boundary key after attachment header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$upload_name=$_FILES["your_file_input_name"]["name"];
$upload_type=$_FILES["your_file_input_name"]["type"];
$upload_size=$_FILES["your_file_input_name"]["size"];
$upload_temp=$_FILES["your_file_input_name"]["tmp_name"];

$subject = "Your Subject";
$to="example@example.com";
$message="Your Message";

$fp = fopen($upload_temp, "rb");
$file = fread($fp, $upload_size);

$file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
$num = md5(time());

//Normal headers

$headers  = "From: Info Mail<example@example.com>\r\n";
$headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers  .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers  .= "boundary=".$num."\r\n";
$headers  .= "--$num\r\n";

// This two steps to help avoid spam

$headers .= "Message-ID: <".gettimeofday()." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\r\n";

// With message

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
$headers .= "".$message."\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\n";

// Attachment headers

$headers  .= "Content-Type: application/".$upload_type." ";
$headers  .= "name=\"".$upload_name."\"r\n";
$headers  .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers  .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
$headers  .= "filename=\"".$upload_name."\"\r\n\n";
$headers  .= "".$file."\r\n";
$headers  .= "--".$num."--";

// SEND MAIL
$flgchk=@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
fclose($fp);

if($flgchk)
{
    echo 'Sent Successfully';
}
else
{
    echo 'Unexpected error occurred!!! Please try again.';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last boundary, finish the mail with the last attachment string only, this removes the noname.txt in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

```
$header = "From: Info Mail<example@example.com>\r\n";
          $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$num."\"\r\n\r\n";
          $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
          $header .= "--".$num."\r\n";
          $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
          $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
          $header .= "--".$num."\r\n";
          $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$upload_name."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
          $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
          $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fname."\"\r\n\r\n";
          $header .= $file."\r\n\r\n";
          $header .= "--".$num."--";
```

I used the above headers for mails which seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect

change the code here.

In Attachment headers

Replace

```
$headers  .= "Content-Type:".$upload_type." ";
```

with

```
$headers .= "Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; ";
```

Comment: check once `$upload_name` has a value or not.